# How to use the powershell azure API to get see why the service is busy

Tags: powershell, azure

We use the powershell API defined at

Publish-AzureServiceProject

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/publish-azureserviceproject?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

However we found the the call hangs. ie the server is **busy**. We then went to the azure portal and found that we were missing a dll in the deployment. This in itself is not a big deal but why does the call to **Publish-AzureServiceProject hang** instead of erroring out?

[image]

The actual command given was

```
[15:52:36][PublishAzureWebsite] Publish-AzureServiceProject -Package 'C:\tca\tick\712fd6c47ab9a6e5\azurewebsite\Weingartner.Distribution.Azure.cspkg' -Slot Staging -Configuration 'C:\tca\tick\712fd6c47ab9a6e5\azurewebsite\ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg'
```

which then generates

```
[15:52:37][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] For a list of all Azure cmdlets type 'get-help azure'.
[15:52:37][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] For a list of Windows Azure Pack cmdlets type 'Get-Command *wapack*'.
[15:52:41][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] 
[15:53:17][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] Id                                       Type Subscriptions                        Tenants                             
[15:53:17][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] --                                       ---- -------------                        -------                             
[15:53:17][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] research@weingartnergmbh.onmicrosoft.com User XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX...
[15:53:17][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell]                                                                                                                        
[15:53:19][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: 15:53:19 - Verifying storage account 'weingartnerdistribution'...
[15:53:20][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: Publishing weingartnerdistribution to Microsoft Azure. This may take several minutes...
[15:53:20][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: 15:53:20 - Connecting...
[15:53:22][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: 15:53:22 - Uploading Package to storage service weingartnerdistribution...
[15:53:59][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: 15:53:59 - Starting...
[15:55:05][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: 15:55:05 - Created Deployment ID:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX .
[15:55:05][PublishAzureWebsite] [powershell] WARNING: 15:55:05 - Initializing...
```

and then hangs. This then blocks our CI pipeline and it is not obvious for thereader of the log what has gone wrong. Is it possible to get the diagnostic that is shown in the portal to be available to the powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use following cmdlet.

```
Get-AzureWebSiteLog -Name webappname -Tail
```

You also could download deployment logs.

```
Save-AzureWebSiteLog -Name webappname
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).